# ¿Còmo mostrar una windows de tkinter (python) del tamaño exacto de mi LCD raspberri 3.5"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para raspberry y trabaje con un monitor por salida hdmi como mi pantalla de 3.5" tiene de resolucion 480x320 hice la ventana con esa geometria, pero al probar el programa en la LCD de 3.5" no abarca toda la pantalla ¿como puedo hacer que abarque toda la pantalla?

Comment: Posiblemente se deba a que en los 480x320 se esté incluyendo el ancho del borde y de la barra de título. Tendrías que crear una ventana sin borde, o quizás usar el modo fullscreen. Por desgracia no puedo ayudarte más, pues no sé apenas nada de tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)


root.mainloop()
```